# Extract data from span, using BeautifulSoup, python

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to extract data from span **using BeautifulSoup**, but somehow it is throwing an error.

**HTML**

```
<td style="text-align:right"><span class="sc-15yy2pl-0 hzgCfk"><span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>3.69<!-- -->%</span></td>
<td style="text-align:right"><span class="sc-15yy2pl-0 hzgCfk"><span class="icon-Caret-down"></span>5.33<!-- -->%</span></td>
```

**My code to extract span data**

```
page_content= BeautifulSoup(http.html, 'html.parser')
content= page_content.td.contents
data= content.span.string
```

I Want to extract 3.69% & 5.33% from span tag.

Comment: What's the errror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using find_all method

You can use find_all() method to find the text content of html
and use just your own link

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = requests.get(yourUrl)
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "html.parser")

tds = soup.find_all("td")

contents = []
for td in tds:
  content = td.find("span", {"class":"sc-15yy2pl-0 hzgCfk"}).find("span", {"class":"icon-Caret-down"}).text
  contents.append(result)
```